# Struct which returns the value of a field with the same syntax used for (say) an Int

Tags: c#, struct

It's likely that I'm just confused and wouldn't want to do this if I knew better, but here goes:

When you have `int myInt = 5;` you can access the value of that int just by calling the name of the variable: `int myOtherInt = myInt + 1;` or `myInt ++;`.

I have a struct that I want to behave this way, and return an existing value type.

In short, the struct has a Func field, and provides the result of that function; it also has Min/Max fields you use to clamp the output regardless of the raw result of the function.

```
Func<Foo, int> _func;
int _min;
int _max;

public MyStruct(Func<Foo, int> func, int min, int max) {...}

// Doesn't work
public int this 
{ 
    get { return Clamp(_min, _max, _func()); }
}

Clamp(min, max, val) {}
```

So, I want to be able to write:

```
var myStruct = new MyStruct((myFoo => myFoo.IntVal * 5), 1, 1000);
int myInt = myStruct + 5;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options for you here. You can define an [implicit casting operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx), or you can define each of the [arithmetic operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx) you're interested in.

Here's a full example of using the implicit cast operator. No `this` property needs to be implemented.

```
using System;

public struct MyStruct
{
    public static implicit operator int(MyStruct myStruct)
    {
        return 2;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myStruct = new MyStruct();
        var myInt = myStruct + 5;
        Console.WriteLine("Int value: {0}", myInt);
    }
}
```

In this case, `myStruct + 5` implicitly casts your struct into an integer, using the overloaded operator you've implemented.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out the Implicit operator:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2(v=vs.71).aspx it has limitations, but could 
get you a long way.

A nice post that does into examples and one of it's limitations:
http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2009/02/22/c-implicit-operator/

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by implementing `public static implicit operator int(MyStruct astruct)` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2(v=vs.71).aspx for more details.) and also an `operator +` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467(v=vs.71).aspx for a tutorial).

```
public static MyStruct operator +(MyStruct astruct, int IntVal)
{
    // code to add an int to the underlying value of your struct
}

public static implicit operator int(MyStruct astruct)
{
    return return Clamp(_min, _max, _func());
}
```

with that, I think

```
int myInt = myStruct + 5;
```

should work, calling `operator +` for `myStruct + 5` and then `implicit operator int` for the `myInt =` part.

Comment: well, I was assuming we would leave the "this" definition in.

Comment: the `this` property thing isn't valid syntax.  The `(int)this` line will attempt to explicitly convert `this` to an `int`, which by default will fail unless there is a `public static explicit operator int(MyStruct m)` implementation too.

Comment: yup I finally got it. :) thanks for pointing it out. clearly time for me to hit the sack. I was thinking they meant it didn't work for the assignment to int, just didn't actually go through the whole process of thinking it through.

Comment: Thank you for working this out. I wish I could accept your answer too because it completes Dan Cecile's answer nicely. His got me there first though.

Comment: no worries, glad to hear you got your issue taken care of! no need to worry so much about who you give credit, giving it to whoever solved your problem makes perfect sense to me :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just overload the `operator +(MyStruct a, int b)`

A tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: That's a good point. I'm after this particular behavior, but thanks for that link, I didn't know about that.